# Form set admin django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am a beginner programmer
Qiez project
There is a task in admin
On one page
Ability to add questions/answers to questions/mark correct answers on the test set page

Tried
NestedStackedInline, NestedModelAdmin

Lots of settings
Is there a better option